# How do I turn a C++ class into managed class and call the pure virtual function inside?

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pure-virtual

It looks likes this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define __dllexport extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 

class PureVirtual
{
public:
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
};

class ImplPureVirtual : public PureVirtual
{
public:
    void Foo()
    {
        printf("Moo");
    }
};

__dllexport PureVirtual* GetPV();
```

In implementation:

```
#include "ManagedClass.h"

PureVirtual* impl = new ImplPureVirtual;

__dllexport PureVirtual* GetPV()
{
    return impl;
}
```

It compiled as TestFoo.dll, Then in C#

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string strFileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string strProcName);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ptrLib = LoadLibrary("TestFoo.dll");
        if (ptrLib != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            var ptrAddr = GetProcAddress(ptrLib, "GetPV");
            if (ptrAddr != IntPtr.Zero)
                // Now we have the pointer object, what should I do next?
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I think it's a pretty good problem, that if a software company released their unmanaged API to the public(with only pure virtual method), and if we could control the wisdom of C++ abstractive and polymorphism, then we could make it into managed and have several benefit! Such as Garbage control, generics, and a wide choices of references and libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would also need to define an `extern "C"` function for each virtual member; managed code cannot call unmanaged C++ exports in an easy or portable way due to C++ name mangling.  For example:

```
__dllexport void PureVirtual_Foo(PureVirtual * pv)
{
    pv->Foo();
}
```

Also, consider that you need to catch C++ exceptions in the `extern "C"` wrappers, because an uncaught exception can skip over managed stack frames, causing the CLR to get into a bad state.

I would strongly suggest that you look into using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).  It is able to automatically generate these wrappers for you.

---

Note that you do not need to use `LoadLibrary()` etc., you can just P/Invoke the function:

```
[DllImport("TestFoo")]
public static extern IntPtr GetPV();
```

Likewise, to call the virtual method given my example wrapper:

```
[DllImport("TestFoo")]
public static extern void PureVirtual_Foo(IntPtr pv);
```

Then you could call the virtual method like this:

```
PureVirtual_Foo(GetPV());
```

Comment: If I would like to use SWIG, will there be any overhead?

Comment: @SteveFan Probably not significantly more overhead than if you manually created the wrapper library.  Or, to put it another way, P/Invoke itself already adds quite a bit of overhead, so any overhead added by the SWIG wrappers are unlikely to be noticeable in comparison.